# webdriverio cucumber outline // play all scenarios even if one is having a failure

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io, outline

I am using an outline examples in my test,
something like :

Feature: feature name

Scenario Outline: outline scenario
Given I go to 
When I click on button
Then I should have

Examples:
| website  | title |
| google   | google welcome|
| yahoo    | yahoo welcome |
| Astalavista    | altalavista hello I m dead |

so far it is great !!! but if the first one is doing okay and the second one is having an issue the third is not played ...

do you know how to continue all the test in case of outline scenario ?

thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

There is something called `failFast` in the cucumberOpts.

If the value is `true` then it means fail at the first failure and do not proceed.

If the value is `false` then the execution will continue for all the scenario in the feature file even if one scenario fails.

So try by making it as `false`.

Thanks,
Naveen